# Sending a message to a Kafka Broker using TCP Sockets and Deno

Tags: apache-kafka, protocols, deno, tcpsocket

We are trying to create a Kafka client using Deno and TCP sockets. As a first step, we are trying to ping a broker we have running on a docker instance using the below code:

```
  import {
  Client,
  Packet,
  Event,
} from 'https://deno.land/x/tcp_socket@0.0.1/mods.ts';

const client = new Client({
  hostname: 'localhost',
  port: 9092,
});

for (let i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
  // Connection open
  client.on(Event.connect, (client: Client) => {
    console.log('Connect', client.conn?.remoteAddr);
  });

  // Receive message
  client.on(Event.receive, (client: Client, data: Packet) => {
    console.log('Receive', data.toString());
  });

  // Connection close
  client.on(Event.close, (client: Client) => {
    console.log('Close');
  });

  // Handle error
  client.on(Event.error, (e) => {
    console.error(e);
  });

  // Do
  await client.connect(); // Start client connect
  await client.write('Hello World'); // Send string data
  await client.write(new Uint8Array()); // Send Uint8Array data
  client.close();
}
```

We are successfully pinging the broker, but receive the following error:

```
[2021-08-13 00:20:36,472] WARN Unexpected error from /172.20.0.1; closing connection (org.apache.kafka.common.network.Selector)

org.apache.kafka.common.network.InvalidReceiveException: Invalid receive (size = 1214606444 larger than 104857600)

at org.apache.kafka.common.network.NetworkReceive.readFromReadableChannel(NetworkReceive.java:91)

at org.apache.kafka.common.network.NetworkReceive.readFrom(NetworkReceive.java:71)

at org.apache.kafka.common.network.KafkaChannel.receive(KafkaChannel.java:169)

at org.apache.kafka.common.network.KafkaChannel.read(KafkaChannel.java:150)

at org.apache.kafka.common.network.Selector.pollSelectionKeys(Selector.java:365)

at org.apache.kafka.common.network.Selector.poll(Selector.java:313)

at kafka.network.Processor.poll(SocketServer.scala:494)

at kafka.network.Processor.run(SocketServer.scala:432)

at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

[2021-08-13 00:28:19,708] INFO [Group Metadata Manager on Broker 0]: Removed 0 expired offsets in 0 milliseconds. (kafka.coordinator.GroupMetadataManager)
```

We understand that this is due to a protocol issue and are trying to determine what the best way forward is to address this issue. Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Can you clarify why you cannot use `kafkajs` or `node-rdkafka` for their existing protocol implemention?

Comment: We are trying to implement a Kafka client in Deno. Therefore, we cannot use npm modules. Our next step in troubleshooting is to try and replicate the network and protocol components in the kafkajs repository, but we are not sure this implementation will work

Comment: I'm not sure why it wouldn't work, but you'd be a lot better off if leveraging librdkafka if you can interface with C/C++ libraries from Deno. Otherwise, I assume you've already tried the Node compatibility bridge? https://deno.land/std@0.104.0/node/README.md

Comment: That stack trace seems to be coming from your Kafka container right? Also, seems like you're using a third-party lib to establish a TCP connection, potentially using the builtin Deno namespace might be a better solution, at least in terms of support. There could be a lot of different things going on, you can also try hopping in our Discord server and brainstorm there, maybe someone will have a more concrete idea to help you.